# java.io.NotSerializableException while passing object between activitites

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am trying to pass my custom object from an activity to another. So I used the below code:

In welcomeActivity.java: (Implements serializable also QuestionRepository.java implements serializable as well)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this,QuestionActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("category", 1);
intent.putExtra("qustionRepository", questionRepository);
startActivity(intent);
```

In questionActivity.java:

```
questionRepository = (QuestionRepository) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("questionRepository");
```

In run time, I got this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.user.loginactivity, PID: 16608
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.user.repository.QuestionRepository)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1316)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1264)
                  at 
     ...
               Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.user.repository.BaseRepository_Impl$4
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
                  at 
     ...
```

BaseRepository is an interface which extends serializable.

```
@Dao
public interface BaseRepository extends Serializable {

@Query("SELECT * FROM User")
List<User> getAllUserScores();

@Query("SELECT * FROM user where first_name LIKE  :firstName AND last_name LIKE :lastName")
User findUserByName(String firstName, String lastName);

@Insert
void insertUser(User user);

@Delete
void deleteUser(User user);

@Insert
void insertQuestion(Question question);

@Delete
void deleteQuestion(Question question);

@Query("Select * from Question")
List<Question> getAllQuestions();
}
```

As I can find from my researchs, implementing serializable is enough to pass objects between activites but appearently I missed something. Where am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Serializable` for complexe object, you need to implement Parcelable which required a lot of boilerplate, i would recomand a library as Parceler (https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) to make it easier

Comment: Now I can go to QuestionActivity activity but my questionRepository does returns null after this runs: "questionRepository = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("questionRepository");" in Question activity. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

> implementing serializable is enough to pass objects between activites

Yes, but to implement `Serializable`, everything the Java class holds onto in fields must itself be `Serializable`. In this case, you did not write the Java class — it is code-generated for you by Room.

Your `RoomDatabase` that has `BaseRepository` should be a singleton; both activities can then access that singleton to work with the `BaseRepository`.

In general, passing arbitrary objects via `Intent` extras is a code smell. Android has to make 2+ copies of those objects as part of starting up the other component (in this case, starting an activity), and those copies get passed between OS processes.

Comment: Now I got the background of the error, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The `com.example.user.repository.BaseRepository_Impl$4` is [a generated class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Dao.html) that according to the exception doesn't implement `Serializable`.
Passing a DAO from an activity to another makes no sense. Service/Dao instances are dependencies and stateless. So instead you should inject them in each activity/component where they are needed.

Comment: How can I inject these to my QuestionActivity class?

Comment: Dagger 2 for example.